# Failed to install Slim framework on windows

Tags: php, api, frameworks, composer-php, slim

when i try to installing Slim framework by Composer,and when i write (composer require slim/slim "^3.0"), show me the error as in picture:

[image]

note that I have successfully installed the Composer? thank you very much.

Comment: what happens if you run command prompt as administrator?

Comment: i get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a directory where composer is installed. Open the directory in command prompt and type the command:

```
composer require slim/slim "^3.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your user is not allowed to create files in root of drive C. Try making a new directory somewhere you're allowed to do so, and switch to that directory, then run `composer require slim/slim "^3.0"` again. This directory could be a new directory on your Documents folder, or Desktop, etc. You have write permissions for those directories.

Comment: it is the same error? i cannot upload image in comment